# Error in SQL query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

I´m trying to run the following SQL code on access 2010, but it returns syntax error in query expression. Any ideas what could be causing it?

Thanks in advance.

```
DELETE FROM Trn_done 
WHERE (Trn_done.training = 
SELECT Training  
FROM Trainings 
WHERE (Trainings.Area = '" & Area & "'))
```

Comment: Are you sure the `SELECT` returns a unique row?

Comment: Please use parameterized queries and stop concatenating the `Area` in there... it's not best practice the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bracket should be before the nested SQL as mentioned below

```
DELETE FROM Trn_done
WHERE Trn_done.training IN (
    SELECT Training 
    FROM Trainings
    WHERE (Trainings.Area = '" & Area & "')
)
```

Comment: @wagregg It can be done with an EXISTS also.  They all work just fine.

Comment: @RBarryYoung But over and over again I see the use of `IN` signifying inexperience and misconception. One should use `JOIN` or `EXISTS` instead of `IN`, in every situation where possible. I have seen a 4-level deep nested `IN` query with `OR`s and `AND`s that was extremely difficult to understand. It took me 20 minutes to rewrite it as a simple query using `INNER JOIN`, which could then be understood in a few seconds. So don't be promulgating the use of `IN` as "working just fine". Anyone can write code a computer can understand. But we should write code for *humans* to understand.

Comment: @ErikE With all respect, I couldn't disagree more. What I see is the many sql experts who should know better propagating the long-standing myth that `IN(..)` is necessarily bad or slower than `EXISTS` or `JOIN`, and that just is not generally true. *Generally*, in cases where they are logically the same, modern SQL optimizers will produce the same query plan. And the claim that `IN` is easier for "*humans*" to understand is an opinion that has no basis in fact: beginners prefer `IN` *because* it's easier to understand. Please stop promoting these myths as facts.

Comment: @RBarryYoung You're right, `IN` is not slower, and I never claimed that it was--nice red herring. As for what beginners prefer: you're right, at one level deep `IN` is easier to understand than a `JOIN`. So are cursors, procedural logic instead of set-based, overusing variables, and a host of other things that don't "come naturally" to beginners to the SQL world. Those are hardly reasons to avoid what seasoned SQL professionals instinctively recognize as better habits! Just use `JOIN`s. Anything else is silly. Beginners need to learn, and that is why we share a better way with them!

Comment: @ErikE So, given that the "Nested `IN`s argument does not apply to the answer that we are commenting on, making it both a strawman and a red herring, you literally have no reason for your position that `IN` shouldn't be used other than that you think that "serious professionals just use `JOIN`s"? Do you have anything at all to support that claim because it has no basis in *my* experience. The serious SQL professionals that I know and work with decide whether to use `JOIN`, `IN`, `EXISTS`, etc. on a case-by-case basis, there's no blanket rule to never use `IN` or that `JOIN` is always better.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I will freely admit that perhaps my experience has led me astray. My apologies for overstating the case about seasoned SQL professionals--clearly others have different thoughts on the topic. The top SQL-kung-fu that I see on SO just doesn't have this `IN` behavior, and so often `IN` marks poor queries. I still believe that encouraging the use of `IN` subqueries--even one deep--is a disservice to beginners. If one way to write a query lends itself to easy modification and another to needless complexity, it seems an easy choice! It's a maintenance, clarity, and consistency problem.

Comment: @ErikE Fair enough, let's just say that we disagree about this then.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't EQUAL a select statement, lest multiple rows in your select cause your code to break.  Try this instead:

```
DELETE td 
from Trn_done td
inner join Trainings t 
on td.training = t.training
WHERE t.Area = '" & Area & "'
```

Comment: You can EQUAL a `SELECT` statement if you're sure that this `SELECT` returns exactly **one** row.